# Unable to complete new 'Cloud Profile' setup in TeamCity using Azure Resource Manager Cloud Support plugin

Tags: azure, plugins, configuration, teamcity

I am running On-Premises TeamCity Professional, version 2023.11.3

Recently I have installed plugin Azure Resource Manager Cloud Support, version 0.12.1

Now I need to create new 'Cloud Profile' within TeamCity project administration of type 'Azure Resource Manager', but I am struggling to finish this step, because as a credential type I'd like to use azure managed service identity, but when I select this option in the form, there is red error message as on the image below.

[image: img01]

At this point I am unable to finish cloud profile creation in terms of adding new image, since for that the subscription is needed. The profile itself can be created (which is weird with missing mandatory subscription), but it's obviously useless, because there is no image defined.

When I tried the other credential option - service principal, new fields appear to fill in tenant Id, application id and application key, but this option is not preferred.

I've tried to get some info in TeamCity documentation, the plugin's TeamCity blog post and also plugin's github pages, but the iformation there is overall vague and lot re-used from the old plugin version which used portal classic and the only option was to create VM on azure using service principal.

Am I missing some other configuration here which prevents me to setup this succesfully ?